# demonstrate the use of loops and ifs to simulate results of rolling a single die multiple times

Tags: python

Assigntment is as follows, just looking for guidance on how to track the number of times a roll number appears, this is what I have so far, I was working off a simple guessing game program I wrote. Any guidance/explanation would be great. NOT looking for the text for the entire code or answers. I just need a understanding of how to track, and implementing the counter code. Here is what I have:

## a simple simulation that can help show that the probability of any die face value is equal

import random

NumberToGuess = (random.randint(1,6))
print('The dice roll is ' + str(NumberToGuess))

GuessRoll = input('How Many Times Does The Die Need To Be Rolled To Get The Dice Roll: ')
GuessRoll = int(GuessRoll)

while (GuessRoll != NumberToGuess):

```
if (GuessRoll > NumberToGuess):
    print ('Guess is TOO high ')
else:
    print ('Guess is TOO low ')
GuessRoll = input('Guess the number: ')
GuessRoll = int(GuessRoll)
```

print('You are the WINNER!!')

1. Ask the user how many times the die needs to be rolled. This value should be stored in an
   appropriate variable.
2. A loop must be executed the number of times the user specified in 1. above.
3. Inside the loop, a random number between 1 and 6 (inclusive) is generated.
4. The number of times a number appears is kept track of. A simple approach is to have a variable
   (a counter) for each die value. As the random die roll is generated, the corresponding counter is
   incremented by 1. For example, you could have a variable called Roll1 that keeps track of the
   number of times a 1 is rolled. And each time a 1 is rolled, the variable has 1 added to it.
5. When the loop ends, a report is displayed on the screen showing the count of each die value.
   There should be 6 values displayed in a user friendly manner. As simple output might look like
   this:
   Number of times 1 is rolled: xx
   Number of times 2 is rolled: xx
   Number of times 3 is rolled: xx
   Number of times 4 is rolled: xx
   Number of times 5 is rolled: xx
   Number of times 6 is rolled: xx
   where the xx’s are the total number of times that specific number appeared

Comment: What is your question? This is simply a series of *commands*

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is basically just you asking someone to do something for you, rather than help you accomplishing doing it yourself. Is there anything  you've attempted that you can show?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: No sorry I am not asking someone to do it for me, I need guidance, I did have some work I’ll put up tomorrow, and what I am having trouble with.

Comment: I've added what I have so far, was looking for some guidance on how to implement a counter to track the rolls as well.

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT! 
Took a lot of trial and error, reviewing a lot of other tutorials on while and if loops etc. But I got it slowly but surely.

```
Counter = 1
Counter1 = 0
Counter2 = 0
Counter3 = 0
Counter4 = 0
Counter5 = 0
Counter6 = 0

RollNumber = input('How Many Times Do You Want To Roll The Dice: ')
RollNumber = int(RollNumber)

import random

while Counter <= RollNumber:
   DieRoll = (random.randint(1,6))
   Counter = Counter + 1
if DieRoll == 1:
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
if DieRoll == 2:
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
if DieRoll == 3:
    Counter3 = Counter3 + 1
if DieRoll == 4:
    Counter4 = Counter4 + 1
if DieRoll == 5:
    Counter5 = Counter5 + 1
if DieRoll == 6:
    Counter6 = Counter6 + 1
print ('Number 1 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter1)
print ('Number 2 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter2)       
print ('Number 3 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter3)
print ('Number 4 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter4)
print ('Number 5 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter5)
print ('Number 6 was rolled this many times:')
print (Counter6)

print ('Thanks For Playing The Dice Roll Simulator')
```